# Multiple where condition in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Hi I am trying to run a result on calendar where if booking is done fetch result including Accomodation ID and Property type. The first condition on where works not the second and third, don't know what am I doing wrong. Below is my code, from my model.

```
$this->db->where("FromDt between '$fromdate' AND '$toDate' OR toDate between '$fromdate' AND '$toDate' OR '$fromdate' between FromDt AND toDate OR '$toDate' between FromDt AND toDate");
    $this->db->where('AccomId =', 5);
    $this->db->where('propertytype =', 1);
```

The first code which is checking the dates is working not the next two I have even tried

```
$this->db->where('AccomId', 5);
    $this->db->where('propertytype', 1);
```

Expecting your valuable support, Thank you in Advance
Sunil

Comment: **WARNING**: Use placeholder values. **DO NOT** use string interpolation on values like `$fromdate`.

Comment: However that part of where clause is working not the next 2, is it because of the mentioned warning other 2 not working?

Comment: It's "working" but it has a bug so huge someone could wreck your company and career with it.

Comment: According to the documentation this should be expressed as the second form, `where('x', y)`, *not* the first.

Comment: However the first one works, and only if I remove the first the second and third works, can you suggest any other option for the first to check between dates

Comment: That first `WHERE` clause is really confused. Can you simplify it? Why is it checking variable vs. columns and then columns vs. variable?

Comment: If the booking is from 18 feb to 21 feb the and if the search starts before 18 and ends after 21 first variables v columns, and if the search starts 19 and ends 20th the column vs variable works

Comment: read about [Codeigniter's Query Grouping](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in#query-grouping)

Comment: Thank you for your support I fixed by using this code $this->db->where("'$fromdate' between FromDt AND toDate AND AccomId = 1 AND propertytype = 2 OR '$toDate' between FromDt AND toDate AND AccomId = 1 AND propertytype = 2");

Answer (score 0):

you're stating multiple OR statements. Because you're starting with OR and then checking the other two values, the other two values are interpreted like they belong to the last OR statement.

Im guessing you always want to check the two values AND it should have one of the OR values. I changed it for you, so you can try if this fixes it.

```
$this->db->where('AccomId', 5);
$this->db->where('propertytype', 1);
// or statement
$this->db->where("FromDt between '$fromdate' AND '$toDate'");
$this->db->or_where("toDate between '$fromdate' AND '$toDate'");
$this->db->or_where("toDate between '$fromdate' AND '$toDate'");
$this->db->or_where("'$fromdate' between FromDt AND toDate");
$this->db->or_where("'$toDate' between FromDt AND toDate");
```